# How to parse json string in map or list

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

Please help for parse json response. My json String is

```
  {  
   "result":[  
      {  
         "parent":"",
         "made_sla":"true",
         "caused_by":"",
         "watch_list":"",
         "upon_reject":"cancel",
         "sys_updated_on":"2019-05-09 15:36:38",
         "child_incidents":"0",
         "hold_reason":"",
         "approval_history":"",
         "number":"INC0000060",
         "resolved_by":{  
            "link":"https://dev59401.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user/5137153cc611227c000bbd1bd8cd2007",
            "value":"5137153cc611227c000bbd1bd8cd2007"
         },
         "sys_updated_by":"admin",
         "opened_by":{  
            "link":"https://dev59401.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user/681ccaf9c0a8016400b98a06818d57c7",
            "value":"681ccaf9c0a8016400b98a06818d57c7"
         },
         "user_input":"",
         "sys_created_on":"2016-12-12 15:19:57",
         "sys_domain":{  
            "link":"https://dev59401.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user_group/global",
            "value":"global"
         },
         "state":"7",
         "sys_created_by":"employee",
         "knowledge":"false",
         "order":"",
         "calendar_stc":"102197",
         "closed_at":"2016-12-14 02:46:44",
         "cmdb_ci":{  
            "link":"https://dev59401.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/cmdb_ci/109562a3c611227500a7b7ff98cc0dc7",
            "value":"109562a3c611227500a7b7ff98cc0dc7"
         },
         "delivery_plan":"",
         "impact":"2",
         "active":"false",
         "work_notes_list":"",
         "business_service":{  
            "link":"https://dev59401.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/cmdb_ci_service/27d32778c0a8000b00db970eeaa60f16",
            "value":"27d32778c0a8000b00db970eeaa60f16"
         },
```

Comment: Try with https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/.

Comment: I use herokuapp  but we cant got solution

Comment: @ShivPatel If you believe your question is not a duplicate, you need to [edit] the body of your post to show clearly what you have tried and what specific issue you are struggling with.

Comment: https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/ produced code for me when I fixed the JSON. What specific problem did you have?

Comment: +1 with @KeithC , i also got  file after fixed JSON